# Suggestion for a bronze badge: the perfectionist

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request

If an user edits an answer or question several times in a short period just after have posted the Q or A.

Comment: FGITW would be a better name for it.

Comment: What positive behavior would this badge encourage?

Comment: Edit until let everything perfect. :) ok, it would be just a fun (easter egg) badge.

Comment: I would rather give a perfectionist badge to Q&As with zero edits and a positive score.

Comment: I can notice the sense of humor here does not seem the best.

Comment: We need one for a question that gets unfunnier the more the OP edits it.

Comment: @BoltClock: _"Digger"_. Description: _"<username>... Wat r u doin? <username>... Stahp!"_

Comment: Would an edit from someone else kill your perfection? If word got out we'd be looking at 7,000 badges per day for questions alone. Add a dumb answer, edit it a few times, you'll get a badge. How would it reward perfection if it didn't also encourage the perfection of old posts? A badge for "a bit of perfection" or "I'm on the wagon, perfect now"?

Comment: This badge should be hidden for the badge list and it can be given only once. It was like a "surprise" to who post then polishes the post to perfection.

Comment: It is best to put everything in your proposal up front. Hopefully you realise now that an extra encouragement for FGITW is not at all needed. Badges are to reward desired behaviour (which obviously can be exploited for badges by pretending). So no hidden badges. Wouldn't make sense.

Comment: If the badge was not hidden, it could be an incentive to new users to use the "edit" feature to polish answers.

Comment: But why encourage FGITW? We may not need to criminalize it, but we'd much rather people take their time to perfect their answers from the get-go (see @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå's comment). Neither of these things needs a badge.

Comment: Suffering heavy cyberbullying.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli: [Voting on meta is different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Just to add to that, it's not "bullying" when people disagree with you.

Comment: Closed... _"This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope defined in the help center."_ Really? A badge suggestion is off-topic?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A badge like that would only encourage excessive editing, possibly making it harder to write an answer, since the question keeps getting modified.

It's too easy to just go in and change a few characters around until you get the badge.

I don't see how the badge would benefit the site. In an ideal world, posts would *never* need to be edited.

Comment: An ideal world, that could mean no questions in the first place, or anything else one wishes to invent. Not sure that line adds anything. Good answers on good questions would be penalised with no badge.

Comment: _"Good answers on good questions would be penalised with no badge."_?  What do you mean? Not adding this badge would penalize those posts? The ideal world comment was meant to illustrate that the reason behind posts being edited isn't usually to improve an already good post. Usually, edits are made to make crap posts decent. (or to fix mistakes). Not exclusively to improve good posts.

Comment: No. If the badge existed, perfection would mean editing a post several times. So an unchanged post would not be regarded as perfect. Yes, I understand the ideal world bit, but just think there are other ways to say that which don't have the problem of injecting free-for-all-imagination were something can just be invented to counter your (invented) case. Just getting a badge for the comment. Anyway. OP has given up.

Comment: @Cerbrus this badge would not be an "incentive badge" but just a fun one. This should be hidden, like an easter egg. It happens often when you answer with a piece of code and then you realize that there was a better way to do that and then you edit, edit, polishing to perfection.

Maybe this would not be suitable for questions, but for answer would be nice.

I will accept this answer as correct anyway.

Comment: Then I really don't see the point.

Comment: A little joy is that bad? If I received a badge that way I would be happy. Actually, if the badge was not hidden, it could be an incentive to new users to use the "edit" feature to polish answers.

Comment: You're assuming edits are made to polish good posts. This is usually not the case, edits are usually only made to fix mistakes, or to make poorly formatted posts readable. I really don't see the point in adding a badge that's really trivial to obtain.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like there are the perfectionists who insist on not acknowledging that lesser beings actually make mistakes, or may lack a perfect vocab, or perfect logic, or perfect anything much at all... what about relaxing a bit and allowing genuinely imperfect people to ask genuine - but imperfect questions - in an attempt to learn from someone more able than themselves? I thought that was the point of SO?

Comment: I thought the point of SO was [to build a library of detailed answers to your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), which isn't saying much of anything about imperfection...

Comment: Sure, but the process to achieve those answers might be a little more forgiving of those who are not brilliant or articulate in their first attempts.